# How to alter object server-side before save in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to run certain insert statements after a collection has been updated. For example, if a user adds an embedded document Location to their User document, I would like to also insert that embedded document into a separate Location collection. Is there a way to do this on the server side so that the operation is guaranteed to run?

Comment: I am aware that you can call a method server side to do both the update and insert, but that would have the negative consequence of removing latency compensation from what I understand.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you would need to do it in a method.. you can keep latency compensation by implementing a client-side Method stub:

> Calling methods on the client defines stub functions associated with
>   server methods of the same name. You don't have to define a stub for
>   your method if you don't want to. In that case, method calls are just
>   like remote procedure calls in other systems, and you'll have to wait
>   for the results from the server.
>
> If you do define a stub, when a client invokes a server method it will
>   also run its stub in parallel. On the client, the return value of a
>   stub is ignored. Stubs are run for their side-effects: they are
>   intended to simulate the result of what the server's method will do,
>   but without waiting for the round trip delay. If a stub throws an
>   exception it will be logged to the console.

see my Meteor stub example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145432/1029644

Comment: Do you have example of how to implement said stubs? I am looking at some examples on StackOverflow such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231712/when-to-use-meteor-methods-and-utilizing-stubs) but I am still a little confused as to how to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to use some code I wrote (https://gist.github.com/matb33/5258260), you can hook in like so:

EDIT: code is now part of a project at https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

```
var test = new Meteor.Collection("test");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    test.before("insert", function (userId, doc) {
        doc.created = doc.created || Date.now();
    });

    test.before("update", function (userId, selector, modifier, options) {
        if (!modifier.$set) modifier.$set = {};
        modifier.$set.modified = Date.now();
    });

    test.after("update", function (userId, selector, modifier, options, previous) {
        doSomething();
    });
}
```