# Why is console.log() not working client-side when inside Meteor methods?

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor, client, console.log

I want to define the same method for both client and server, so I have the following code inside `common/methods.js`.

```
Meteor.methods({
    doSomething: function (obj) {
        if(this.isSimulation) {
            console.log('client');
        }
        if(!this.isSimulation) {
            console.log('server');
        }
        console.log('both');
        return "some string";
    }
});
```

Then I called this method inside `client/dev.js`.

```
Meteor.call('doSomething', someObj, function (e, data) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(data);
});
```

On the server's console, I can read:

```
I20150622-21:56:40.460(8)? server
I20150622-21:56:40.461(8)? both
```

On the client's (Chrome for Ubuntu v43.0.2357.125 (64-bit)) console, the `e` and `data` arguments are printed, but the `console.log()` from the Meteor method is not, where I expected it to output the strings

```
client
both
```

**Why do `console.log()` not work on the client inside Meteor methods?**

---

To debug, I split the `Meteor.methods` into separate client and server code. Then introducing a large loop so the server-side operation so it takes a long time to complete, while the client-side is very quick.

**server**

```
doSomething: function (obj) {
    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i< 9999999; i++) {
        x++;
    }
    console.log(x);
    return "some string";
}
```

**client**

```
doSomething: function (obj) {
    console.log('client');
}
```

Still, no message is printed on the client.

Comment: what does console.log(this.isSimulation) give you?

Comment: @Robin It gives me `false` on the server and nothing at all on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @kainlite for helping me debug this together. It turns out the problem was a simple one of [file load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

I defined my methods in `common/methods.js`, whereas my client-side calls were made in `client/dev.js`, which gets loaded first.

So when the call was made the method wasn't defined, hence it won't run. Moving the `methods.js` file inside the `/lib` directory fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Methods are only executed on the server, they are the *sync* way of doing a remote call.

> Methods
>
> Methods are server functions that can be called from the client. They
>   are useful in situations where you want to do something more
>   complicated than insert, update or remove, or when you need to do data
>   validation that is difficult to achieve with just allow and deny.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-users

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I thought by defining it in a place accessible on both client and server (it's in `common/methods.js`), then the Meteor method will be ran on the client as a stub. Please correct my understanding.

Comment: Methods as stated in the docs only run in the server, if you want code to run on both the server or the client you've to place it under a folder called lib, or common, but not on client, server, or methods... also you need not to define it as a method if it's intended to run on client and server...

Comment: I can recommend you to read this ebook: [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) to get you started and so you can understand how everything fits togheter...

Comment: Thanks for your help kalnlite, and I have read the relevant part of Discover Meteor. Please help me by taking look at [this answer[(http://stackoverflow.com/a/13145432/2317532) where a stub is defined on the client using `Meteor.methods`.

Comment: I see your point, that's part of latency compensation, so your changes will be made immediately on the client, but it will only be final or effective when the servers returns from the method call, is that clear?

Comment: Yes I understand latency compensation, so why is the `console.log()` not printing anything. I expect that to be printed immediately.  Even when I make the server-side operation take a while by using a big loop, the client-side stub is still not running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81191/discussion-between-kainlite-and-dayuloli).